# Equivalence of load() and dump() functions from Php 'EasyRdf' in Python 'rdflib'

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib, easyrdf

I recently started working with Knowledge Graphs and RDFs, and I was fortunate enough that someone provided me with an introductory excercise, which helped me implement some basic functionalities on a local Apache server using Php and EasyRdf. My long-term goal is to make use of NLP and Machine Learning libraries, which is why I switched to Python and the rdflib library.
As far as I know, after reading the documentation of rdflib and several plugins, there is no equivalence for the load() and dump() functions that are available in EasyRdf.

**Background**

- I used load() in Php for loading URLs that conform with the GraphStore protocol, which allows the retrieval of content from a specific graph
- I then use dump() for a readable output of a graph (without checking the pages source text)

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$graph=new EasyRdf\Graph();
print "<br/><b>The content of the graph:</b><br/>";
$graph->load("http://localhost:7200/repositories/myrepo/rdf-graph/service?graph=".urlencode("http://example.com#graph"));
print $graph->dump();
?>
```

**My Question**

My question now is what the most straightforward solution would be to implement something similar to the given example in Python using rdflib. Did I miss something or are there just no equivalent functions available in rdflib?
I already used the SPARQLWrapper and the SPARQLUpdateStore for a different purpose, but they are not helping in this case. So I would be interested in possibilities that are similar to the use of the EasyRdf\Http\Client() from EasyRDF. A basic example of mine in Php would be this:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$adress="http://localhost:7200/repositories/myrepo?query=";
$query=urlencode("some_query")
$clienthttp=new EasyRdf\Http\Client($adress.$query);
$clienthttp->setHeaders("Accept","application/sparql-results+json");
$resultJSON=$clienthttp->request()->getBody();
print "<br/><br/><b>The received JSON response: </b>".$resultJSON;
?>
```

Much thanks in advance for any kind of help.

**UPDATE**

There actually seems to be no equivalent in rdflib to the dump() function from easyRDF, as Python is not a language for web pages (like PHP is), so it does not have default awareness of HTML and front-end stuff. The only thing I managed was to parse and serialize the graph as needed, and then just return it. Although the output is not lovely, the graph content will be correctly displayed in the page's source.

Regarding the load() function, this can be achieved by using the respective URL that is needed to access your repository in combination with a simple request. In the case of GraphDB, the following code worked out for me:

```
# userinput is provided in the form of a Graph URI from the repository
def graphparser_helper(userinput):
    repoURL = "http://localhost:7200/repositories/SomeRepo/rdf-graphs/service?"
    graphURI = {"graph": userinput}
    desiredFormat = {"Accept": "text/turtle"}
    myRequest = requests.get(repoURL, headers=desiredFormat, params=graphURI)
    data = myRequest.text
    return data
```

I hope that helps someone.

Comment: loading a graph in `rdflib` is in-memory. If you want to load it into a triple store, use SPArqlWrapper and SPARQL `LOAD`